# Increase heap memory when building native image with Spring native

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image, spring-native, native-maven-plugin

When building a native image of a Spring Boot application I'm getting this:

```
Terminating due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
The Native Image build process ran out of memory.
Please make sure your build system has more memory available.
```

Is there a command line flag I can pass to Maven to tell it to increase the heap size? I know I could go into the `native-maven-plugin` and add some configuration, but I'd prefer to do it via the command line when I run `./mvnw -Pnative -DskipTests native:compile`.